# Hide/Destroy a gridview Android

Tags: android, gridview

I need to have multiple gridviews in my activity and the user will be calling by clicking a button, is it possible to destroy a gridview after hiding it?

This is what I have in mind,

1- here the user clicked button1 so I'll be viewing gridview1

```
button1      button2       button3
---------------------------------
|                                | 
|      Gridview1 visible         |
|                                |
|                                |
---------------------------------
```

2- Here the user clicked button2 so I'll be viewing gridview2, so I'll need to hide/destroy Gridview1

```
button1      button2       button3
---------------------------------
|                                | 
|      Gridview2 visible         |
|                                |
|                                |
---------------------------------
```

3- And finally button3 will hide/destroy all gridviews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "destroying" the gridview, but here is how you can hide them:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {
         gridView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         gridView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     } 
}); 

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {
         gridView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         gridView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     } 
}); 

button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {
         gridView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         gridView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     } 
});
```

Or you can keep just one gridview and populate its data each time a button is pressed like this:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {
         //Populate your new data to ArrayList etc.
         gridview.notifyDataSetChanged();
     } 
}); 

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {
         //Populate your new data to ArrayList etc.
         gridview.notifyDataSetChanged();
     } 
}); 

button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) 
     {
         //Empty your data.
         gridview.notifyDataSetChanged();
     } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks bigO, so what I'm thinking about is memory consumption and I was thinking if I only hide the view that might be not efficient, right?

Comment: But then when you click, let's say, button 1 and make gridView1 visible, you will need to recreate gridview1 and that is another cost

Comment: maybe keep one grid view and change the adapter?

Comment: yes, you can keep just one gridview and populate its adapter each time a button is clicked. That is more memory efficient than keeping two gridviews. Just change the data of your adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged().